# Rspec: is it possible to should_receive on a class?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Question is in the title. Lets say for example I've got a class:

```
class A
  def self.something
    p 'Something'
  end

  def call_something
    self.class.something
  end
end
```

I want to write a test, that an `instance a` of `class A` on method call: `a.call_something` will actually call `A.something`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about trying it? I guess that works

```
describe '#call_something' do
  it 'calls something in classA' do
    a = ClassA.new
    ClassA.should_receive(:something)
    a.call_something
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the questioner, who is trying to invoke a class method.